# Is it possible to run background operation in RxJava after "Unsubscribe"?

Tags: concurrency, rx-java

Is it possible to run background operation in rxJava after "unscription"?

Ex: I create a stream of 3 strings: A, B, C and I introduce high latency for C and the same latency for A and B. By using the operator first() I unsubscribe too fast to C and C does not have the time to be executed so the unscription kill C. Is there a easy way to leave  C continuing running in the background???

```java
    @Test
    public void test_69_b() throws Exception {
        List<String> intList = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C");
        print("start");
        Observable test = Observable.from(intList)
                                    .flatMap(this::findWrapperS)
                                    .first();
        print("build finnished");
        test.subscribe(this::printAtSub);
        print("End");
        Sleeper.sleep(Duration.ofSeconds(4));
    }

    private Observable<String> findWrapperS(String id) {
        return Observable.just(id).doOnUnsubscribe(() -> {
            print("Wrapper <" + id + "> is released");
        })
                         .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
                         .flatMap(i -> Observable.fromCallable(() -> sendBackString(i)));
    }

    private String sendBackString(String string) {

        switch (string){
            case "C":
                Sleeper.sleep(Duration.ofMillis(1000));
                print("Hello " + string);
                return string;

            default:
                Sleeper.sleep(Duration.ofMillis(10));
                print("Hello " + string);
                return string;
        }
    }
```

```
Given logs
=================
18:19:47.806 [Test worker] INFO tests.TestRunner - Got: start
18:19:47.831 [Test worker] INFO tests.TestRunner - Got: build finnished
18:19:47.989 [Test worker] INFO tests.TestRunner - Got: End
18:19:47.994 [Test worker] INFO tests.Sleeper - Sleeping PT4S ms
18:19:47.998 [RxIoScheduler-2] INFO tests.Sleeper - Sleeping PT0.01S ms
18:19:47.999 [RxIoScheduler-3] INFO tests.Sleeper - Sleeping PT0.01S ms
18:19:47.999 [RxIoScheduler-4] INFO tests.Sleeper - Sleeping PT1S ms
18:19:48.009 [RxIoScheduler-3] INFO tests.TestRunner - Got: Hello B
18:19:48.010 [RxIoScheduler-3] INFO tests.TestRunner - TERMINAL EVENT --->: B
18:19:48.012 [RxIoScheduler-3] INFO tests.TestRunner - Got: Wrapper <A> is released
18:19:48.013 [RxIoScheduler-3] INFO tests.TestRunner - Got: Wrapper <C> is released
18:19:48.015 [RxIoScheduler-3] INFO tests.TestRunner - Got: Wrapper <B> is released
18:19:48.015 [RxIoScheduler-2] INFO tests.TestRunner - Got: Hello A
18:19:48.021 [RxIoScheduler-4] WARN tests.Sleeper - Sleep interrupted
java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Thread.java:340)
    at java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.sleep(TimeUnit.java:386)
    at tests.Sleeper.sleep(Sleeper.java:24)
    at tests.TestRunner.sendBackString(TestRunner.java:249)
    at tests.TestRunner.lambda$null$15(TestRunner.java:242)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeFromCallable.call(OnSubscribeFromCallable.java:48)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeFromCallable.call(OnSubscribeFromCallable.java:33)
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.onNext(OperatorMerge.java:250)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.onNext(OperatorMerge.java:147)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(OnSubscribeMap.java:77)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber.call(OperatorObserveOn.java:227)
    at rx.internal.schedulers.CachedThreadScheduler$EventLoopWorker$1.call(CachedThreadScheduler.java:228)
    at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
18:19:48.023 [RxIoScheduler-4] INFO tests.TestRunner - Got: Hello C
```

Comment: Necessarily, an observer chain needs to have a subscriber to operate. You can share a subscription so that one subscriber leaving does not terminate the observer chain. Any remaining subscribers will leave when the chain completes, and the observer chain will free up its resources.

Comment: @BobDalgleish please, show me how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a long-running observable that you want to complete, the simplest way to do it is to introduce the `share()` operator. It will have two subscribers, an empty one that ensures the process completes, and the other one that takes the `first()` item and unsubscribes.

As always, you need to be concerned with the lifetimes of your objects and release resources when they are no longer viable.

```
// Hold on to long running subscriptions so we can release
// them at the proper time
CompositeSubscription longRunningSubscribers = new CompositeSubscription();
...
private Observable<String> findWrapperS(String id) {
    Observable<String> obs = Observable.just(id).doOnUnsubscribe(() -> {
        print("Wrapper <" + id + "> is released");
       })
      .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
      .flatMap(i -> Observable.fromCallable(() -> sendBackString(i)))
      .share();
      Subscription longTerm = obs
        .subscribe( ignored -> {}, error -> {} );
      longRunningSubscribers.add( longTerm );
      return obs;
}
```

Now, `findWrapperS()` returns an observable that can be subscribed to and unsubscribed to without stopping the long-running operation. When the operation terminates, the observer chains resources will be released. However, you will still likely need to call `longRunningSubscribers.unsubscribe()` at the end of your processing to free up subscribed resources. If everything has finished, then all it does is free up a small amount of memory, which is not a bad thing.

Comment: Thanks, @BobDalgleish, 
It is worked quite well but I am concerned about when to call longRunningSubscribers.unsubscribe() because in a real use case, sendBackString(i) represents a system for which I do not know the latency times. Is it dangerous to performance point view  to leave longRunningSubscribers "not unsubscribed".

Comment: It is not dangerous to leave an observer chain subscribed. The issue is with resource leaks. If an observer chain completes, either normally or with error, then resources used by the chain are freed up. However, the subscription itself holds on to some small amount of memory which eventually should be freed up.

Comment: If I leave an observer chain subscribed, the operator cache() could also be solution (see my response below )? what you think?

Answer (score 0):

@BobDalgleish what if I try "cache() before the first()"?:

```
@Test public void test_69_b() throws Exception {
    List<String> intList = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C");
    print("start");
    Observable test = Observable.from(intList)
                                .flatMap(this::findWrapperS)
                                .cache();
                                .first();
    print("build finnished");
    test.subscribe(this::printAtSub);
    print("End");
    Sleeper.sleep(Duration.ofSeconds(4)); 
}
```

I feel it is a bit similar your proposition in the meaning that cache keep the emitted observables sequence for second subscribers.

Comment: By using `cache()`, you are storing all values emitted. I believe this is wasteful as you will never use them. The side effect of keeping the observer chain operational is better handled with a second subscriber, perhaps adding `ignoreElements()` to ensure no items are kept around.